# Quadratic formula $x = \frac{- (b +\sqrt{b^2- 4ac})}{ \pm2a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the proof of the quadratic formula
$$x = \frac{- b +\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2a}$$
shouldn't there be $\pm 2a$ instead of $2a$, since both can be  the square root of $4a^2$?

Comment: In fact, we have two roots (if $b^2-4ac$ , the discriminant , is positive) , one with "-" and one with "+" , usually this is written as "$\pm$"

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x}$ cannot be both, per convention it is defined as the non-negative solution $r$ of $r^2=x$ , therefore we need the "$\pm$" to get two solutions.

Comment: Yes, it is. See [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Comment: You say this formula appears in a proof. It is indeed the formula for one of the roots, provided it is written $x = - b/(2a) +\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}/(2a)$ or $x = -\frac{b}{2a} + \frac{\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2a}$ so that you are dividing by $2a$ rather than dividing by $2$ and multiplying by $a$. The formula for the other root is $x = -\frac{b}{2a} - \frac{\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2a}.$

Comment: You have to consider all the rest of the proof to determine whether the formula is written correctly and why it is or is not correct. If you can show the steps of the proof up to the point where this formula appears, someone might be able to explain what's going on here.

Comment: Note that the formula $-\frac{b}{\pm 2a} + \frac{\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{\pm 2a}$ would generally give one false root and omit one true root if both $\pm$ signs are chosen the same way.

Comment: What if +- sq root b^2 -4ac/+-2a

Comment: In the [Derivation Section of the Quadratic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Derivations_of_the_formula), which is a specific section in the article already referred to in the comment of Mauro ALLEGRANZA, a step-by-step derivation is given.  This should answer your analytical questions.

Comment: Incidentally, I (for one) am unable to comprehend what you are asking in this comment: "What if +- sq root b^2 -4ac/+-2a".  Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to express math at MathSE, and please try to make your question(s) very clear.

Comment: Of course not, since that would mean that the two roots of any quadratic are always opposites (additive inverses) of each other, which of course, is false.

Comment: If you change sign of denominator in $x_1$, then your fraction changes sign and you'll get $x_2=-x_1$. This number will be root of equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ only in the case when $b=0$.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to just let other people edit your question into something different than what you asked. It tends to happen when you don't format your equations yourself, but you can fix it. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make a guess that the proof you were looking at has the following equation in one of its steps:

$$ \left(x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2 = \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}. $$

This tells us that $x+\dfrac{b}{2a}$ is one of the square roots
of $\dfrac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}.$
But it could be either the positive or negative square root.

The square roots of $\dfrac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$ are
$\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ and $-\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}.$
You can verify this by squaring each one:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\right)^2 &= \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}, \\
\left(-\frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\right)^2 &= \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}. \\
\end{align}

Notice that $-\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ is just
$\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ with its sign flipped.
That is, one of these is a positive square root and one is a negative square root.
Which one is the positive root and which is the negative root depends on the sign of $a,$ but no matter which sign $a$ has we still have both roots, the positive and the negative.

Therefore we have found that the following statement is true:

$$
 \text{$x + \frac{b}{2a}$ is either
 $\frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ or $-\frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$}.
$$

Another way to write the same statement is

$$ x + \dfrac{b}{2a} = \pm\dfrac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}. $$

Now just subtract $\dfrac{b}{2a}$ from both sides and you have the usual quadratic formula.

At no point in any of this did we ever take a square root of $4a^2.$
Instead, we looked at the expression $\dfrac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$ and found its square roots
— both of them — and included both roots in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$ax^2+bx+c=0,~~~a\neq0$$

$$\begin{align}
&\Rightarrow x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}a=0\\
\\
&\Rightarrow\left(x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=0\\
\\
&\Rightarrow\left(x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}\\
\\
&\Rightarrow\left(x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}}\\
\\
&\Rightarrow x+\frac{b}{2a} =\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2|a|}\\
\end{align}$$

Case.(1) $a>0\Rightarrow |a|=a$

$$x+\frac{b}{2a} =\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \Rightarrow x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Case.(2) $a<0\Rightarrow |a|=-a$

$$x+\frac{b}{2a} =\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{-2a} \Rightarrow x=\frac{-b\mp\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Therefore, no matter what cases, you get the same formula.

Comment: case 2 +- and - from 2a= -+-

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach it which does not rely on the study of the sign of $a$:
\begin{align*}
ax^{2} + bx + c = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow 4a^{2}x^{2} + 4abx + 4ac = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (4a^{2}x^{2} + 4abx + b^{2}) = b^{2} - 4ac\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (2ax + b)^{2} = b^{2} - 4ac\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2ax + b = \pm\sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!